# WPF MVVM changing parent window viewmodel from icommand execution

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, icommand

I'm currently in the process of mastering the C# WPF MVVM pattern and have stumbled upon a pretty big hurdle...

What I am trying to do fire off a `LoginCommand` that when successfully executed will allow me to change the parent window's viewmodel. The only issue is I can't quite think of a way to change the parent window's viewmodel without breaking the MVVM design pattern because I can't access the parent window's `ContentControl` that sets its path to the active `UserControlViewModel` in the window.

Here's the scenario:

In our `App.xaml` we have two DataTemplates:
`<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:LoginViewModel}">
    <Views:LoginView />
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:LoggedInViewModel}">
    <Views:LoggedView />
</DataTemplate>`

In our `MainWindow` we have:
`<ContentControl Content="{Binding ViewModel}" />`
The `MainWindow` code behind will set the `ViewModel = LoginViewModel`

In our `LoginViewModel` we have:
`<Button Command="{Binding LoginCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=pwPasswordBoxControlInXaml}" />`

Now for the money... the `LoginCommand`:
`public void Execute(object parameter)
{
    // Do some validation
    // Async login task stuff
    // ...
    // Logged in... change the MainWindow's ViewModel to the LoggedInViewModel
}`

How can I make the Execute method change the window's viewmodel without breaking the MVVM pattern?

Things I've tried thus far:

- Making the MainWindow have a static Instance singleton that I can access and then change the `ViewModel` property from the command.
- Attempting to implement some form of routed command listener in the MainWindow and then have commands fire off routed command events to be handled by the parent window.

Comment: I'd suggest you want a `MainWindowViewModel` or `ApplicationViewModel` which handles the navigation and sets the current `Workspace` (`LoginViewModel` or `LoggedInViewModel`). There's a nice example at [Navigation with MVVM](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/). In that, the various views are bound to buttons, but in your case you'd simply want the login button to fire a command to validate, then switch as appropriate. (sample code also available there)

Comment: Ok but how would the LoginCommand get an instance of the ApplicationViewModel to execute the ChangeViewModel command? @Tone

Comment: The `LoginCommand` would be defined in the `ApplicationViewModel`, not in the `LoginViewModel` (this `ApplicationViewModel` would be the `DataContext` for the `Window`).

Comment: So say you might have your validation defined in a public method in your `LoginViewModel`, and the command on your `ApplicationViewModel` just calls that method and switches to `LoggedInViewModel` if it passes whatever validation you have there.

Comment: I'll try to get something like that working. Only issue I see is that if I remove the LoginCommand from the LoginViewModel then I won't be able to pass along things like the username, password, etc that I use to actually log-in;

Comment: Been working on a sample, I'll post as an answer. I've tried to keep it as simple as possible but there isn't really a right and wrong way to do it, you have a lot of choices. Give me a couple of minutes to post it up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done a quick demo to show one way of doing it. I've kept it as simple as possible to give the general idea. There are lots of different ways of accomplishing the same thing (e.g. you could hold a reference to `MainWindowViewModel` inside `LoginViewModel`, handle everything there then call a method on `MainWindowViewModel` to trigger the workspace change, or you could use Events/Messages, etc).

Definitely have a read of [Navigation with MVVM](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/) though. That's a really good introduction that I found helpful when I was getting started with it.

The key thing to take away from this is to have an outer `MainWindowViewModel` or `ApplicationViewModel` which handles the navigation, holds references to workspaces, etc. Then the choice of how you interact with this is up to you.

In the code below, I've left out the clutter from defining `Window`, `UserControl`, etc. to keep it shorter.

Window:

```
<DockPanel>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentWorkspace}"/>
</DockPanel>
```

MainWindowViewModel (this should be set as the `DataContext` for the `Window`):

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    LoginViewModel loginViewModel = new LoginViewModel();
    LoggedInViewModel loggedInViewModel = new LoggedInViewModel();

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        CurrentWorkspace = loginViewModel;

        LoginCommand = new RelayCommand((p) => DoLogin());
    }

    private WorkspaceViewModel currentWorkspace;
    public WorkspaceViewModel CurrentWorkspace
    {
        get { return currentWorkspace; }
        set
        {
            if (currentWorkspace != value)
            {
                currentWorkspace = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public ICommand LoginCommand { get; set; }

    public void DoLogin()
    {
        bool isValidated = loginViewModel.Validate();
        if (isValidated)
        {
            CurrentWorkspace = loggedInViewModel;
        }
    }
}
```

LoginView:

In this example I'm binding a `Button` on the `LoginView` to the `LoginCommand` on the `Window` `DataContext` (i.e. `MainWindowViewModel`).

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding UserName}"/>
    <Button Content="Login" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Path=DataContext.LoginCommand}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

LoginViewModel:

```
public class LoginViewModel : WorkspaceViewModel
{
    private string userName;
    public string UserName
    {
        get { return userName; }
        set
        {
            if (userName != value)
            {
                userName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public bool Validate()
    {
        if (UserName == "bob")
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

LoggedInView:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding RestrictedData}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

LoggedInViewModel:

```
public class LoggedInViewModel : WorkspaceViewModel
{
    private string restrictedData = "Some restricted data";
    public string RestrictedData
    {
        get { return restrictedData; }
        set
        {
            if (restrictedData != value)
            {
                restrictedData = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

WorkspaceViewModel:

```
public abstract class WorkspaceViewModel : ObservableObject
{
}
```

---

Then some other classes you probably already have implemented (or alternatives).

ObservableObject:

```
public abstract class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,
            new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

RelayCommand:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> execute;
    private readonly Predicate<object> canExecute;

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    { }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
        }

        this.execute = execute;
        this.canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return canExecute == null ? true : canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        execute(parameter);
    }
}
```

App.Xaml:

```
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:LoginViewModel}">
        <Views:LoginView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:LoggedInViewModel}">
        <Views:LoggedInView />
    </DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding ViewModel}">
  <ContentControl.Resources>
     <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:LoginViewModelClass}">
        <!-- some LoginView -->
     </DataTemplate>

     <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:LoggedInViewModelClass}">
        <!-- some LoggedInView -->
     </DataTemplate>
  </ContentControl.Resources>
</ContentControl>
```

Comment: Sorry, this does not help

Comment: maybe I did`t understand the question